# Is there economic/intuitive reason why the treynor-black model favour low delta instruments?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, call, treynor-black

In the treynor-black model optimal instrument weights are proportional to:
$w_i =  \frac{\frac{\alpha_i}{\sigma_i^2}}{\sum_j \frac{\alpha_j}{\sigma_j^2} }$.

Let Instrument 1 be a stock with $\alpha_1$ and $\sigma_1^2$ and let Instrument 2 be a call option with 50 delta on instrument 1. Then for Instrument 2 we have $\alpha_2 = \delta* \alpha_1$ and $\sigma_2^2 = \delta^2 \sigma_1^2$.

Simply plugging in these parameters will show that the model gives a higher weight to instrument 2. Is there any reason (intuitive) reason why the model would favour the call option over the stock? Or is this purely an "artefact" because the model was designed with stocks in mind?

Answer (score 2):

So after thinking a bit about it I found the solution:

The formula in the treynor-black model only applies if the covariance matrix of the idiosyncratic risk is independent. The introduction of a call option, is locally simply a (de)leveraged version of the stock.

From a optimization perspective the call option is (locally) redundant. Therefore we can not simply plug in the values in the formula.

So it was a case of using the correct formula for the wrong situaton.